# Getting the Browser Version - Java - Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webclient

I just started to learn selenium. I am trying to retrieve the browser version while perform headless browser testing but receiving errors. Can anyone explain the reasoning and how I can resolve the issue. Thanks!

here is my code:

```
package HtmlUnitDriver;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import org.htmlunit.WebClient;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.*;

public class HtmlUnitDriverTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.EDGE);

        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");

        System.out.println("Title is:" + driver.getTitle());

        WebClient webClient = (WebClient) get(driver, "webClient");

        System.out.println("Browser version is:" + webClient.getBrowserVersion());

        System.out.println("Is browser version chrome?:" 
        + webClient.getBrowserVersion().isChrome());
        System.out.println("Is browser version firefox?:" 
        + webClient.getBrowserVersion().isFirefox());

        driver.quit();

    }

    private static Object get(Object object, String field) throws Exception {
        Field f = object.getClass().getDeclaredField(field);
        f.setAccessible(true);
        return f.get(object);
    }

}
```

I am expecting to have a print out of the version and also false statements for the isChrome() and isFireFox() checks... but instead I get this error:

`Title is:Facebook - log in or sign up     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: webClient     at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2610)  at HtmlUnitDriver.HtmlUnitDriverTest.get(HtmlUnitDriverTest.java:34)    at HtmlUnitDriver.HtmlUnitDriverTest.main(HtmlUnitDriverTest.java:21)`

Comment: the error is telling you that driver has no such field "webClient".  (WebDriver has no such field...)  This is thrown when you do Field f = object.getClass().getDeclaredField(field);  It'll be simpler to use getBrowserVersion() method.... though you may want to type to HTMLUnitDriver first.  Unclear why you are checking for this...